# Files in /data/data/app.dir/files directory deleted

Tags: android, delete-file

I have an android application in which I copy some files from assets to the files directory(internal storage). Everything works fine, but once in a while, these files get deleted. I added a file observer to the directory and I see the delete event. My application does not have any delete code. So I am stumped as to what event/condition is deleting the files in the files directory. Anyone face similar issues?